# How to create custom popup in tridion?

Tags: 2013

How to create custom popup in tridion which will be shown when execute method gets called?

In GUI extension while executing the . _execute method I would like show custom popup modal. Not that browser popup.

I want to create new modal popup and display that when ._execute function gets called. This ._execute function is getting called on one button click.

So that's I am trying to achieve. Please let me know as early as possible if anyone know anything.

Comment: Can you provide more details and your use case? Without many details I can say that GUI extensions is what you need.

Comment: Can you also highlight what you've looked at/read/tried?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, @Dipak. In terms of use case, it would indeed help to edit your question to add where you're trying to create such a pop-up. For example, is this for editors or for visitors of your website?

Comment: In GUI extension while executing the . _execute method I would like show custom popup modal.

Comment: In GUI extension while executing the . _execute method I would like show custom popup modal.
Not that browser popup. I want to create new modal popup and display that when ._execute function gets called.
This  ._execute function is getting called on one button click. So that's I am trying to achieve. 
Please let me know as early as possible if anyone know anything.

Answer (score 1):

To open your own popup, you simply call the *createExternalPopup* method of the *$popupManager* class and pass in the URL and a few other parameters.

For example (taken from [the command](https://github.com/pkjaer/alchemy-plugins/blob/master/CountItems/Static/Commands/CountItems.js#L27) of my open-sourced [CountItems](https://github.com/pkjaer/alchemy-plugins/tree/master/CountItems) Alchemy plug-in):

```
execute: function (selection)
{
    var p = this.properties;
    var selectedItem = this._getSelectedItem(selection);
    var url = "${ViewsUrl}CountItemsPopup.aspx#selectedItem=" + selectedItem;
    var height = this._getPopupHeight(selectedItem);
    var parameters = "width=432px, height=" + height + "px";
    var args = { popupType: Tridion.Controls.PopupManager.Type.EXTERNAL };

    p.popup = $popupManager.createExternalContentPopup(url, parameters, args);
    $evt.addEventHandler(p.popup, "close", this.getDelegate(this.closePopup));
    p.popup.open();
}
```

I recommend implementing your popup window as a View (`this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.View");`) and to fire events when buttons are clicked (such as `fireEvent("close")` to close the popup from the calling `execute` method).

For an example, take a look at the Popup.js file in the CountItems repository. On [line 6](https://github.com/pkjaer/alchemy-plugins/blob/master/CountItems/Static/Scripts/Popup.js#L6), it inherits from `Tridion.Cme.View` and [in the close() method](https://github.com/pkjaer/alchemy-plugins/blob/master/CountItems/Static/Scripts/Popup.js#L136) it calls `fireEvent`.